# Does karate supports mocking of multi-part forms?

Tags: mocking, karate

I need to mock the incoming POST request from service, which headers are:

```
Accept:[application/json] 
Accept-Encoding:[gzip] 
Accept-Language:[en_US] Authorization:[Bearer 123456] Content-Length:[843] 
Content-Type:[multipart/related; boundary=ffab720
```

And body is a content of the file in the base64 format.

Does Karate support mocking of such requests?
I've tried to 'catch all' requests with Karate mock, but the mock returns 500 error to the service and there is no incoming request in the karate log.

Answer (score 0):

Karate indeed can mock multi-part requests, refer this article: https://software-that-matters.com/2021/07/02/mock-a-file-server-with-karate-test-framework/

You may need to double-check how you are calling the mock. For teams trying to troubleshoot mocks, I recommend this thread: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881

Comment: I've tried to configure the mock as it is described in the mentioned article, but it looks like the mock rejects all requests with content-type= multipart/form-data. If I change the value of this header to application-json in the code of microservice, the request is matched in the mock.

Comment: The mock is just like catch all and print incoming info. But I'm getting an error in the log that 'requestParts is not defined' when I'm using this:
    * print 'requestParts:', requestParts

Comment: @EkaterinaA that may be a bug. make sure you are using the latest version of karate. do you think you can follow this process ? https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I'm using the version 1.2.0 and I've also tried to update to 1.3.1 and to 1.4.0 and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @EkaterinaA ok so without any more details or a way to replicate I can't help